# How to 'generalize' the negative binomial distribution when multiple 'experiments' are being performed simultaneously?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Suppose I have 25 dice. I roll them all each day unless the number '6' appears, in which case I discard the die. For example, suppose on day 1, two of the dice roll a 6. I remove them. On the second day, I therefore roll 23 dice. 5 of them land on a 6, so I remove those. On the third day, I roll 18 dice, remove those that land a 6, and so on.

Suppose I have a random variable, $X$, which has three parameters, $k$, $p$, and $n$. $k$ is the total number of dice that have been discarded on or before the $X$th day. $p$ is the probability that an individual die becomes discarded on an arbitrary day (equal to $\frac{1}{6}$ in this example). Finally, $n$ is the number of dice that are rolled each day (25 in this example).

What is the probability distribution of $X$, in terms of its parameters $k$, $p$ and $n$?

Does there exist a standard distribution for $X$? If there was only 1 die, it would be geometrically distributed. If there was one die but you didn't discard the die (simply count the number of 6's), it would be negatively binomially distributed. I'm sure someone has already derived a distribution for this phenomena, but can't locate it. So if anyone knows how to determine the distribution of $X$, that would be great!

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be the first day by which at least $k$ dice have been removed?  If so then I suspect this is unlikely to be a common distribution but finding it should not be too difficult. For each die you can find the probability it has succeeded (been removed) in the first $d$ days (as you say, a geometric CDF).  So you can find the probability at least $k$ have been been removed in $d$ days (related to a binomial CDF).  This gives you a cumulative distribution for $X$.  Subtract the probability that at least $k$ have been been removed in $d-1$ days and you can find $P(X=d)$.

Comment: To answer your first question, yes it is. Based on the logic you outlined, I believe the answer is $f(x) = F_{Bin}\left [k;n=n,\tilde{p}=F_{Geo}\left ( x;p=p \right ) \right ]$, where $F_{dist}$ is the cdf of distribution dist.